# How to set up routing so that Index does show?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

So I know google can penalize a site if you have the same content on multiple urls... unfortunately, in MVC this is too common i can have `example.com/`, `example.com/Home/` and `example.com/Home/Index` and all three urls would take me to the same page... so how do I make sure that whenever `Index` is in the url, that it redirects to the same without the `Index` and of course the same thing with the `Home`

Comment: Check out canonical urls: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to do it without any external Library...

In my `RouteConfig` I had to add these two routes at the top, just below the `IgnoreRoute`

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Root", 
            "Home/",
            new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Home" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Index",
            "{action}/Index",
            new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Home" }
        );
```

Then I had to create a new `Controller` called `Redirect` and I created a method for each of my other `Controller`s like this:

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("~/");
    }

    public ActionResult News()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("~/News/");
    }

    public ActionResult ContactUs()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("~/ContactUs/");
    }

    // A method for each of my Controllers
}
```

That's it, now my site looks legit. No more Home, no more Index in my URLs, this of course has the limitation of not being able to accept parameters to any of the `Index` methods of your `Controllers` though if it was really necessary, you should be able to tweak this to achieve what you want.

Just an FYI, if you want to pass an argument to your Index Action, then you can add a third route like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ContactUs",
            url: "ContactUs/{id}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ContactUs", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This will create a URL like this: `/ContactUs/14`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this little library](https://github.com/haacked/routemagic) may be useful for you.
This library is not very convinient in your case, but it should work.

```
var route = routes.MapRoute(name: "Default",
                            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.Redirect(r => r.MapRoute("home_index", "/home/index")).To(route);
routes.Redirect(r => r.MapRoute("home", "/home")).To(route);
```

Comment: You almost got the Accepted answer but I found a way that doesn't depend on an external library...

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this is for default pages like Index is to simply create an explicit route for only one of them.  I.e. "example.com/People" would be the route for People/Index, and there would be no valid page at the url "/example.com/People/Index".

The Home example is unique in that it has potentially three different URLs.  Again in this case I'd simply create a route for "example.com" for that Index action, and not support the other two urls.  In other words, you would never link to the other forms of the URL, so their absence should never cause a problem.

We use a Nuget package called AttributeRouting to support this.  When you specifiy a GET route for a page, it overrides the defaults for MVC.

Using AttributeRouting usually you'd map the index to `[GET("")]` but for the special case of Home where you also want to also support the root URL that omits the controller name , I think you'd also add an additional attribute with IsAbsoluteUrl:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
     [GET("")]
     [GET("", IsAbsoluteUrl = true)]
     public ActionResult Index()
     {...
```

Comment: An example for how your would setup the routing for the Home, Home/Index and we can use your example of People together, would be most helpful...

Comment: @SerjSagan Added an example

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood my question... this method 1 requires an external library and 2 it doesn't work... it still allows me to go to both `Home/` and `Home/Index/`